# Add-Member to an object strange behaviour

Tags: powershell

I try to add a member "canonicalName" to an object. When I use a Statement:

```
$obj | Add-Member NoteProperty "CanonicalName" 
-value (Get-ADComputer $row.ServerName -Properties CanonicalName).CanonicalName
```

the column "canonicalName" doesn't appear at all.
Using the Statement with a variable:

```
    $a = (Get-ADComputer $row.ServerName -Properties CanonicalName).CanonicalName 
$obj | Add-Member NoteProperty "CanonicalName" -value $a 

works perfectly.
```

**Hint:** some ServerNames I'm Looping through are no more in the Domain.
the code:

```
$data = $dataSet.Tables[0] 
$ErrorActionPreference = "silentlycontinue"
$info = @()
foreach($row in $data)
{ 
    $obj = New-Object psobject
    $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty "ServerName" -Value $row.ServerName
    #$a = (Get-ADComputer $row.ServerName -Properties CanonicalName).CanonicalName 
    #$obj | Add-Member NoteProperty "CanonicalName" -value $a 
    $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty "CanonicalName" -value (Get-ADComputer $row.ServerName -Properties CanonicalName).CanonicalName


    $info += $obj    
}

$info | ft -AutoSize
```

I expect to get:

```
ServerName CanonicalName                                                             
---------- -------------                                                             
N3751022   xx.yy.de/Memberserver/SQL-Cluster/xx/n3887022                 
N3732022   xx.zz.de/Memberserver/yy/uu/zz/N3732022
```

without the variable $a all what I get is (no column canonicalName):

```
ServerName
----------
N3751022  
N3732022
```

I've tested the code in a different Domain (all the Server in the dataset are present in the Domain!) I get the proper result (two columns serverName and canonicalName), even if there is no value for a canonicalName for a given serverName.

Comment: Try extra brackets around `((Get-AdComputer ...).CanonicalName)`

Comment: no difference at all!

Comment: Shouldn't that rather be `foreach($row in $data.Rows)` ?

Answer (score 1):

Using try/catch might be a workaround for you...

*Please note however, that the catch block used in this example is far from precise. Any exception from running Get-ADComputer will be treated the same, we simply just assume that no output from Get-ADComputer means that the computer isn't member of the domain.*

```
$data = $dataSet.Tables[0] 
$ErrorActionPreference = "silentlycontinue"
$info = @()
foreach($row in $data)
{ 
    $obj = New-Object psobject
    $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty "ServerName" -Value $row.ServerName
    try {
            $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty "CanonicalName" -Value (Get-ADComputer $row.ServerName -Properties CanonicalName).CanonicalName
    } catch {
            $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty "CanonicalName" -Value $null
    }

    $info += $obj    
}

$info | ft -AutoSize
```

Comment: thank you. With try and catch block it works fine, but still this behaviour is strange: building a variable $a prevents from error, the column "canonicalName" will be created, no variable: only one column: ServerName is the Output...strange

Comment: As an aside, if you are using `try{..} catch{..}`, I'd suggest you set `$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"` so PowerShell wil treat every exception as terminating and therefore enters the catch block.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it. Using the filter on `Get-ADComputer` will allow it to return null if there is no matching record instead of an error:

```bsh
$data = $dataSet.Tables[0] 
$ErrorActionPreference = "silentlycontinue"
$info = @()

foreach ($Row in $Data) {
    $ServerName =  $Row.ServerName
    $obj = New-Object psobject
    $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty "ServerName" -Value $ServerName
    $CanonicalName = (Get-ADComputer -Filter {Name -like $ServerName} -Properties CanonicalName).CanonicalName
    if ($CanonicalName) {
        $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty "CanonicalName" -value $CanonicalName
    }
    else {
        $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty "CanonicalName" -value $null
    }
    $info += $obj 
}

$info | ft -AutoSize
```